# Function for finding the input for a function outside it?

Tags: python

Is there a function to find the input of another function?

For example the getInput() function would look like:

```py
x = '1'
x = int(x)
print(getInput(x))
```

would say '1', not 1

Is this possible?

This will be the classic way of doing this:

```py
x = input("Enter a number: ")
try:
    int(x)
except:
    pass

if x not in range(0, 10):
    print("str(x)+ "is not a number")
```

instead:

```py
x = input("Enter a number: ")
try:
    int(x)
except:
    pass

orig_x = getInput(x)
if x not in range(0, 10):
    print(orig_x+" is not a number")
```

I know that for this code I could say:

```py
x = input("Enter a number: ")
try:
    int(x)
except ValueError:
    print(x+" is not a number")
```

but when it gets more complicated and a variable gets edited and converted many times that it gets hard to track like when classes and objects are involved, the getInput() function may help.

Comment: Can you give an example of a case where the variable "gets edited and converted many times", and you need to know the original type of the variable? What is the specific problem? Also note that if `getInput` would work as you describe, `getInput(x)` would *never* be in `range(0, 10)`, as it is a string and not a number.

Comment: @user10186512 For example: when an age is entered using `input()`, it is a string, so it is easier to compare the value using `in range()`. Then if I wanted to display it, I could use `print("Your age is: "+str(age))`, but if I want to reuse the `age` multiple times I would just convert `age` to a string again. Here is the problem: if I ever needed to compare the `age` again, I would have to convert it to an integer every time, and then back to a string. I can by pass this by using a function like `getInput()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let me confirm whether i got your question right, You want to get the initial assignment of a variable like so :

```
x = '1'
x = int(x)
print(getInput(x))
```

The output should say '1' and not 1

**Answer** (as far as i know): There is no real use for an interpreter or a compiler to store the past values of a variable. If you really want its past value u can assign a new variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own function?

```
>>> def get_input(message):
...     _input = input(message)
...     if not _input.isnumeric():
...         raise ValueError('Input needs to be numeric')
...     return int(_input)
...
>>> get_input('Enter a number: ')
Enter a number: 10
10
>>>
```